# MATLAB set background color in a cell of uicontrol

Tags: matlab, cell, uicontrol

I want to set a background color in a cell..

**something like:**

[image]

so I have the RGB color and the number of cell I want to color.

you can assume that the position of the cell is what I wrote.

my color is given by RGB:

```
color = [255 0 0];
```

I want to add it in the 10th cell, so I wrote something like:

```
S.cell_data(10) = uicontrol('style','text',...
               'units','pix',...
               'Position',[20 70 80 40],...
               'string',color);
```

but the style is not 'text' and it is no a string.

this is what I'm trying right now:

```
S.cell_data(10) = uicontrol('style','text',...
               'units','pix',...
               'Position',[125 70 80 40],...
               'string','fh');

parentColor = get(get(S.cell_data(10), 'parent'), 'color');

set(S.cell_data(num_of_cols+1),'foregroundcolor', [0 0 0], ...
  'backgroundcolor', parentColor);
```

somebody knows?

Comment: Please elaborate, it is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
blue = 255;
green = 0;
red = 0;

rgb_str = strcat('<HTML><BODY bgcolor = "rgb(', num2str(red), ', ', num2str(green), ', ', num2str(blue), ')">green background</BODY></HTML>');

S.cell_data(10) = uicontrol('Style','pushbutton', 'Position',[20 70 80 40], 'String', {rgb_str});
```

Comment: You don't need strcat (just use square brackets) and I don't think the cast to cell string in the call to uicontrol is necessary, but other than that: good demonstration of using html in uicontrol.

Comment: Be aware that using HTML tags in matlab uicontrols is undocumented, and might not work in future versions.

Comment: @Andrey: As long as MATLAB uses Java Swing for its UI components, then it is pretty safe to use it. Seeing that the entire MATLAB IDE is built in Java, I dont see this changing any time soon :)