# Changing the background color of a table cell in matlab using html content

Tags: matlab, user-interface, cell, background-color, matlab-uitable

we know that [uitable](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uitable.html) supports html content
for an example similar to what I want see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409766/how-to-modify-uitable-cell-color-according-to-data-in-table-in-matlab)
to solve the [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17165914/how-to-change-the-value-and-background-of-a-special-cell-in-table) I asked before I used this code in the callback of a button in matlab:

```
color = uisetcolor;  
numberOfClasses = str2num(get(handles.edtNumClass,'String'));  
if handles.index == 0  
    handles.tableData = cell(numberOfClasses,2);
    guidata(hObject,handles);
end
handles.index = handles.index+1;
handles.tableData(handles.index,1)=cellstr(get(handles.edtNameClass,'String'));
handles.tableData(handles.index,2)=cellstr('<html><span style="background-color:  rgb(color(1,1),color(1,2),color(1,3));"></span></html>');
set(handles.uitable2,'data',handles.tableData);
```

my problem is this line doesn't work:

```
handles.tableData(handles.index,2)=cellstr('<html><span style="background-color:  rgb(color(1,1),color(1,2),color(1,3));"></span></html>');
```

I mean when I open the workspace in matlab I see that handles.tableData(handles.indexes,2) is set to the string.
but the background color does not change
even this html code is not shown as a simple string.
no change happens for the cell!!!
and matlab gives no error message!!!
Note that I even used this code but there was no change.

```
handles.tableData(handles.index,2)=cellstr('<html><span style="background-color:  #FF0000;"></span></html>');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Floris is correct, the string is not "evaluated" as MATLAB code, you need to explicitly write the colors. Here is a small example:

```
%# data
X = {
    'Alice'   1
    'Bob'     2
    'Charlie' 3
    'Dave'    4
};

%# get color from user
c = uisetcolor();

%# format color as: rgb(255,255,255)
%#clr = sprintf('rgb(%d,%d,%d)', round(c*255));

%# format color as: #FFFFFF
clr = dec2hex(round(c*255),2)'; clr = ['#';clr(:)]';

%# apply formatting to third row first column
X(3,1) = strcat(...
    ['<html><body bgcolor="' clr '" text="#FF0000" width="100px">'], ...
    X(3,1));

%# display table
f = figure('Position',[100 100 350 150]);
h = uitable('Parent',f, 'ColumnWidth',{100 'auto'}, ...
    'Units','normalized', 'Position',[0.05 0.05 0.9 0.9], ...
    'Data',X, 'ColumnName',{'Name','Rank'}, 'RowName',[]);
```

[image: screenshot]

---

Note: I tried a few variations of the HTML code. The issue was that the background color was only applied to the text but did not fill the entire table cell:

```
<html><span style="background-color: #FFFF00; color: #FF0000;">

<html><font style="background-color: #FFFF00; color: #FF0000;">

<html><table cellpadding="0" width="100px" bgcolor="#FFFF00" style="color: #FF0000;"><tr><td>
```

[image: screenshot]

The last one worked, but its not better than the previous code I showed. I tried other CSS tricks to fill the entire cell space, but failed. I think that the subset of HTML/CSS supported in Java Swing components is limited.

---

The above [HTML approach](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/html-support-in-matlab-uicomponents/) works fine for small tables. For larger tables or when you want to enable editing, there is a [better approach](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/uitable-cell-colors/). It requires Java Swing familiarity.

Answer (score 3):

Comparing your code (I added line breaks for readability - consider these "on one line"):

```
handles.tableData(handles.index,2)=  ...
  cellstr('<html>
           <span style="background-color: rgb(color(1,1),color(1,2),color(1,3));">
           </span></html>');
```

With the code from your link

```
XX(idx,1) = strcat(...
  '<html><span style="color: #FF0000; font-weight: bold;">', ...
  XX(idx,1), ...
  '</span></html>');
```

There is a Very Important Difference. In the original code, the color is defined as a hex number (which can be interpreted when the HTML is rendered). In your code, the `color` variable is known to Matlab - but it is treated as a string when you create the `tableData`. And the HTML interpreter doesn't know what to do when it comes across `color(1,1)` so it silently ignores the whole command. To fix this, you need to make sure that the string you end up with "makes sense" - i.e. convert `color` to a string. Note - when I looked at the output of `uisetcolor` it appeared that the value returned was between `0` and `1`, not between `0` and `255`; so you want to multiply the color value by 255 first:

```
c255 = color(1,1:3)*255;
colorString = sprintf('rgb(%d,%d,%d)', c255);
```

At this point, `colorString` is `rgb(173,235,255)` (for example).

Now you can create your entire formatstring as

```
formatString = ['<html><span style="background-color: ' colorString ';"></span></html>'];
```

And you can set it:

```
handles.tableData(handles.index,2) = cellstr(formatString);
```

Comment: I used your code but no change happened and I told in the question that even using hex numbers does not make sense

Comment: when I open the workspace I see that cell's value is set to   '<html><span style="background-color: rgb(0,255,255);"></span></html>'
but it does not render when I write the line set(handles.uitable2,'data',handles.tableData)

Comment: Strange. I can't test this right now as I don't have Matlab at home... can you get any other html formatting to work (for example by following the example you linked above)? Does it make a difference whether there is anything in the cell (any text, vs "nothing" in this case)?

Comment: oh yes I tested and understood that I can change the forground color of cell in this way but not the background color

Comment: According to [this earlier answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12918923/matlab-set-background-color-in-a-cell-of-uicontrol) the property name is `bgcolor` and the over all syntax used is slightly different! Let me know if that works then I will update the answer.

Comment: you know in [this earlier answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12918923/matlab-set-background-color-in-a-cell-of-uicontrol) CSS is not used in the HTML code but I have used HTML in my own code

Comment: Well I have written this code and I'm sure that this is write because I have tested it in mozilla but it does not work in matlab. I mean background color of the cell does not change.c255 = handles.color(handles.index,1:3)*255;
colorString = sprintf('rgb(%d,%d,%d)', c255);
formatString=strcat('<html><body bgcolor=',colorString,'></body></html>');
handles.tableData(handles.index,1)=cellstr(get(handles.edtNameClass,'String'));
handles.tableData(handles.index,2)=cellstr(formatString);

Comment: What version of Matlab are you using?